# Use pos tagging in bag of words

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, natural-language

I'm using the bag of words for text classification.
Results aren't good enough, test set accuracy is below 70%.

One of the things I'm considering is to use POS tagging to distinguish the function of words. How is the to go approach to doing it?

I'm thinking on append the tags to the words, for example the word "love", if it's used as a noun use:

```
love_noun
```

and if it's a verb use:

```
love_verb
```

Answer (score 1):

> One of the things I'm considering is to use POS tagging to distinguish the function of words. How is the to go approach to doing it? I'm thinking on append the tags to the words

You approach looks fine. It's unclear whether it'll help though, since the features will be more sparse. Neural networks often give better results, though the improvement isn't considerable  most of the time.